# Trouble processing "javax/xml/XMLConstants.class" in Android

Tags: android, dalvik

I am creating an Application which uses 3 jar files in my libs folder.

- commons-codec-1.8.jar
- jaxp-api-1.4.2.jar
- log4j-1.2.14.jar

When I run the Application, I am getting an error "Dx trouble processing   "javax/xml XMLConstants.class":"

"Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library."

and

"Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1"

I tried with removing the JAR files, but it results in errors in the code.

Please suggest me what I need to do here to solve this issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for my issue.

commons-codec-1.8.jar and jaxp-api-1.4.2.jar were creating the issues since it contains some common class files.  I removed jaxp-api-1.4.2.jar from my project and everything works fine now.

Comment: i have some jar files in my lib folder and i really need them. i can't delete them and one of them is throwing the error in your question. don't know what to do cause San Jaisy answer isn't solving the problem